# Oracle SQL count with date requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables as listed below. I need to list doctor details with the patient he has seen in the last 6 months and the number of patient he had seen.

```
 - Patient

PatientNo | Name | Address | DrNo (FK) | Datevisit

 - Doctor

DrNo | Name | Contact
```

My final output should be as below

```
DrNo | Name | Contact | PatientSeen
```

My coding is definitely wrong, would appreciate some help, totally new to sql.

```
select *, count(select * from patient where drno is not null) 
  from doctor, patient
where doctor.drno = patient.drno
  and trunc(patient.datevisit,'MM') >= trunc(add_months(sysdate,-6), 'MM')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DrNo,
       Name,
       Contact,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM Patient
         WHERE Patient.DrNo = Doctor.DrNo
           AND MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate,Patient.datevisit) <= 6) as PatientSeen
  FROM Doctor
```

Comment: If it is right, could you accept it as a correct answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.DrNo,d.Name,d.Contact,count(p.PatientNo)
from Doctor d left join Patient p on p.DrNo =d.DrNo
where MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate,p.Patient.datevisit) <= 6
group by d.DrNo,d.Name,d.Contact
```

Comment: Your answer will work too but its a bit more difficult for me to understand

Comment: I agree, But joins are preferred approach. It's not that very difficult. Left join means join based on the foreign key and whichever table is on the left will be retrieved fully and only matching entries are considered from the right table.

Comment: You need to `group by` _all_ of the fields in the doctor table that you are selecting. You are missing `Name` and `Contact` in your `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT D.DrNo, D.Name, D.Contact, COUNT(P.PatientNo) AS PatientSeen
FROM DOCTOR D
LEFT JOIN PATIENT P ON D.DrNo = P.DrNo
WHERE P.Datevisit > ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -6)
GROUP BY D.DrNo, D.Name, D.Contact
```